# Trying to get iframe to toggle via button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image comparison slider which I am trying to toggle by user input.  To start I Just want to do it with a simple button, but it won't work, and I can't figure out why.

This is the code I am using:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" class="iframe1" width="300" height="300" src="https://cdn.knightlab.com/libs/juxtapose/latest/embed/index.html?uid=019dc5e8-1631-11e7-9577-0edaf8f81e27"></iframe>
 <button class="button1">toggle slider</button>
```

.

```
function hideToggle(button, elem) {

  $(button).toggle(
   function () {
      $(elem).hide();
   },
    function () {
      $(elem).show();
    }
  );
}

hideToggle(".button1", ".iframe1");
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iboates/pq81z2a9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed your JSFiddle didn't have jQuery, try using the `toggle` function in your `iframe` element, maybe:

```
function hideToggle(button, elem) {
  $(button).click(function() {
    $(elem).toggle();
  });
}

hideToggle(".button1", ".iframe1");
```

Here you can check if is what you're trying to do.

```js
function hideToggle(button, elem) {
  $(button).click(function() { $(elem).toggle('show'); });
}
hideToggle(".button1", ".iframe1");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe frameborder="0" class="iframe1" width="300" height="300" src="https://cdn.knightlab.com/libs/juxtapose/latest/embed/index.html?uid=019dc5e8-1631-11e7-9577-0edaf8f81e27"></iframe>
<button class="button1">toggle slider</button>
```

Comment: `$(elem).toggle();` is enough :)

Comment: oh derp, for some reason i though jsfiddle included jquery by default, thanks.

Comment: @aquaman it makes a little difference adding an animation, although it's okay, thanks!